# xampp not responding when starting apache

Tags: xampp, apache, php

I've recently tried installing php, and I Saw several tutorials that involve modifying my httpd.config and php.ini file, but after I Did what they say, and restarted my computer several times, apache wont start, it just freezes xampp and eventually not responding. here is my httpd.config file:

```
    ServerRoot "C:/xampp/apache"


    #
    #Listen 0.0.0.0:80
    #Listen [::]:80
    Listen 80

    # Default charset UTF8
    # AddDefaultCharset utf-8

    #
    # Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
    #
    # To be able to use the functionality of a module which was built as a DSO you

    #
    # Example:
    # LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so
    #

    LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
    LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
    LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
    LoadModule allowmethods_module modules/mod_allowmethods.so
    LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
    LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
    #LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
    #LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
    LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
    #LoadModule authn_dbd_module modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
    #LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
    LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
    #LoadModule authn_socache_module modules/mod_authn_socache.so
    #LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
    LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
    #LoadModule authz_dbd_module modules/mod_authz_dbd.so
    #LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
    LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
    LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
    #LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
    LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
    LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
    #LoadModule bucketeer_module modules/mod_bucketeer.so
    #LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
    #LoadModule case_filter_module modules/mod_case_filter.so
    #LoadModule case_filter_in_module modules/mod_case_filter_in.so
    #LoadModule cern_meta_module modules/mod_cern_meta.so
    LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
    #LoadModule charset_lite_module modules/mod_charset_lite.so
    #LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
    #LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
    LoadModule dav_lock_module modules/mod_dav_lock.so
    #LoadModule dbd_module modules/mod_dbd.so
    #LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
    LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
    #LoadModule disk_cache_module modules/mod_disk_cache.so
    #LoadModule dumpio_module modules/mod_dumpio.so
    #LoadModule echo_module modules/mod_echo.so
    LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
    #LoadModule example_module modules/mod_example.so
    #LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
    #LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
    #LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so # did not work at runtime
    #LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
    #LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
    LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
    #LoadModule ident_module modules/mod_ident.so
    #LoadModule imagemap_module modules/mod_imagemap.so
    LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
    LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
    LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
    #LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
    #LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
    LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
    #LoadModule log_forensic_module modules/mod_log_forensic.so
    LoadModule cache_disk_module modules/mod_cache_disk.so
    LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
    #LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
    LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
    LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
    LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
    #LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
    #LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
    #LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
    #LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
    LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
    LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
    #LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
    LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
    LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
    #LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
    #LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
    #LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
    #LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
    #LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
    #LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
    LoadModule php5_module "c:/PHP/php5apache2_2.dll"
    <IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
    <IfModule !mpm_winnt_module>
    #
    # If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
    # httpd as root initially and it will switch.  
    #
    # User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
    # It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
    # running httpd, as with most system services.
    #
    User daemon
    Group daemon

    </IfModule>
    </IfModule>

    # 'Main' server configuration
    #

    #

    #

    #
    ServerAdmin postmaster@localhost

    #

    #
    #
    ServerName localhost:80

    #
    # DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
    # documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
    # symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
    #
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"

    #
    # Each directory to which Apache has access can be configured with respect
    # to which services and features are allowed and/or disabled in that
    # directory (and its subdirectories). 
    #
    # First, we configure the "default" to be a very restrictive set of 
    # features.  
    #
    <Directory />
        AllowOverride none
        Require all denied
    </Directory>


    # XAMPP: We disable operating system specific optimizations for a   listening 
    # socket by the http protocol here. IE 64 bit make problems without this.  
    AcceptFilter http none


    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
        #
        # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
        # or any combination of:
        #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
        #
        # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
        # doesn't give it to you.
        #
        # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
        # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
        # for more information.
        #
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI

        #
        # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
        # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
        #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
        #
        AllowOverride All

        #
        # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
        #
        Require all granted

    </Directory>

    #
    # DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
    # is requested.
    #
    <IfModule dir_module>
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.asp index.shtml index.html index.htm \
                       default.php default.pl default.cgi default.asp default.shtml default.html default.htm \
                       home.php home.pl home.cgi home.asp home.shtml home.html home.htm
    </IfModule>

    #
    # The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
    # viewed by Web clients. 
    #
    <Files ".ht*">
        Require all denied
    </Files>


    ErrorLog "logs/error.log"

    #ScriptLog "logs/cgi.log"

    #
    #
    LogLevel warn

    <IfModule log_config_module>
        #
        # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
        # a CustomLog directive (see below).
        #
        LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
        LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

        <IfModule logio_module>
          # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
          LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
        </IfModule>

        #
        # The location and format of the access logfile (Common Logfile Format).
        #
        #CustomLog "logs/access.log" common

        #
        # If you prefer a logfile with access, agent, and referer information
        # (Combined Logfile Format) you can use the following directive.
        #
        CustomLog "logs/access.log" combined
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule alias_module>
        #
        # Redirect: Allows you to tell clients about documents that used to 

        #

        #
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "C:/xampp/cgi-bin/"

    </IfModule>

    <IfModule cgid_module>
        #
        # ScriptSock: On threaded servers, designate the path to the UNIX
        # socket used to communicate with the CGI daemon of mod_cgid.
        #
        #Scriptsock "logs/cgi.sock"
    </IfModule>

    #

    #
    <Directory "C:/xampp/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>


    <IfModule mime_module>
        #
        # TypesConfig points to the file containing the list of mappings from
        # filename extension to MIME-type.
        #
        TypesConfig "conf/mime.types"

        #

        #
        #AddType application/x-gzip .tgz
        #

        #
        #AddEncoding x-compress .Z
        #AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz

        #

        #
        AddType application/x-compress .Z
        AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

        #
        # AddHandler allows you to map certain file extensions to "handlers":
        # actions unrelated to filetype. These can be either built into the server
        # or added with the Action directive (see below)
        #

        #
        AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .asp

        # For type maps (negotiated resources):
        #AddHandler type-map var

        #
        # Filters allow you to process content before it is sent to the client.
        #
        # To parse .shtml files for server-side includes (SSI):
        # (You will also need to add "Includes" to the "Options" directive.)
        #
        AddType text/html .shtml
        AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mime_magic_module>
        #
        # The mod_mime_magic module allows the server to use various hints from the
        # contents of the file itself to determine its type.  The MIMEMagicFile
        # directive tells the module where the hint definitions are located.
        #
        MIMEMagicFile "conf/magic"
    </IfModule>

    #
    #

    #
    #
    #EnableMMAP off
    #EnableSendfile off

    # Supplemental configuration
    #

    # XAMPP specific settings
    Include "conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf"

    # Server-pool management (MPM specific)
    Include "conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf"

    # Multi-language error messages
    Include "conf/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf"

    # Fancy directory listings
    Include "conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf"

    # Language settings
    Include "conf/extra/httpd-languages.conf"

    # User home directories
    Include "conf/extra/httpd-userdir.conf"

    # Real-time info on requests and configuration
    Include "conf/extra/httpd-info.conf"

    # Virtual hosts
    Include "conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf"

    # Distributed authoring and versioning (WebDAV)
    # Attention! WEB_DAV is a security risk without a new userspecific configuration for a secure authentifcation 
    # Include "conf/extra/httpd-dav.conf"

    # Implements a proxy/gateway for Apache.
    Include "conf/extra/httpd-proxy.conf"

    # Various default settings
    Include "conf/extra/httpd-default.conf"

    # Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
    Include "conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf"
    #
    # Note: The following must must be present to support
    #       starting without SSL on platforms with no /dev/random equivalent
    #       but a statically compiled-in mod_ssl.
    #
    <IfModule ssl_module>
        SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
        SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
    </IfModule>

    # Configure mod_proxy_html to understand HTML4/XHTML1
    #<IfModule proxy_html_module>
    #Include etc/extra/proxy-html.conf
    #</IfModule>

    # AJP13 Proxy
    <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    <IfModule mod_proxy_ajp.c>
    Include "conf/extra/httpd-ajp.conf"
    </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    PHPIniDir "C:/PHP"
```

and here's my php.ini file

```
    #
    # NOTE: Where filenames are specified, you must use forward slashes
    # instead of backslashes (e.g., "c:/apache" instead of "c:\apache").
    # If a drive letter is omitted, the drive on which httpd.exe is located
    # will be used by default.  It is recommended that you always supply
    # an explicit drive letter in absolute paths to avoid confusion.

    #
    # ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
    # configuration, error, and log files are kept.
    #
    # Do not add a slash at the end of the directory path.  If you point
    # ServerRoot at a non-local disk, be sure to point the LockFile directive
    # at a local disk.  If you wish to share the same ServerRoot for multiple
    # httpd daemons, you will need to change at least LockFile and PidFile.
    #
    ServerRoot "C:/xampp/apache"

    #
    # Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
    # ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
    # directive.
    #
    # Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
    # prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
    #
    #Listen 0.0.0.0:80
    #Listen [::]:80
    Listen 80

    # Default charset UTF8
    # AddDefaultCharset utf-8

    #
    # Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
    #
    # To be able to use the functionality of a module which was built as a DSO you
    # have to place corresponding `LoadModule' lines at this location so the
    # directives contained in it are actually available _before_ they are used.
    # Statically compiled modules (those listed by `httpd -l') do not need
    # to be loaded here.
    #
    # Example:
    # LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so
    #

    LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
    LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
    LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
    LoadModule allowmethods_module modules/mod_allowmethods.so
    LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
    LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
    #LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
    #LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
    LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
    #LoadModule authn_dbd_module modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
    #LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
    LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
    #LoadModule authn_socache_module modules/mod_authn_socache.so
    #LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
    LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
    #LoadModule authz_dbd_module modules/mod_authz_dbd.so
    #LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
    LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
    LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
    #LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
    LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
    LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
    #LoadModule bucketeer_module modules/mod_bucketeer.so
    #LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
    #LoadModule case_filter_module modules/mod_case_filter.so
    #LoadModule case_filter_in_module modules/mod_case_filter_in.so
    #LoadModule cern_meta_module modules/mod_cern_meta.so
    LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
    #LoadModule charset_lite_module modules/mod_charset_lite.so
    #LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
    #LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
    LoadModule dav_lock_module modules/mod_dav_lock.so
    #LoadModule dbd_module modules/mod_dbd.so
    #LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
    LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
    #LoadModule disk_cache_module modules/mod_disk_cache.so
    #LoadModule dumpio_module modules/mod_dumpio.so
    #LoadModule echo_module modules/mod_echo.so
    LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
    #LoadModule example_module modules/mod_example.so
    #LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
    #LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
    #LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so # did not work at runtime
    #LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
    #LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
    LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
    #LoadModule ident_module modules/mod_ident.so
    #LoadModule imagemap_module modules/mod_imagemap.so
    LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
    LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
    LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
    #LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
    #LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
    LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
    #LoadModule log_forensic_module modules/mod_log_forensic.so
    LoadModule cache_disk_module modules/mod_cache_disk.so
    LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
    #LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
    LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
    LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
    LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
    #LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
    #LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
    #LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
    #LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
    LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
    LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
    #LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
    LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
    LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
    #LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
    #LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
    #LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
    #LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
    #LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
    #LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
    LoadModule php5_module "c:/PHP/php5apache2_2.dll"
    <IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
    <IfModule !mpm_winnt_module>
    #
    # If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
    # httpd as root initially and it will switch.  
    #
    # User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
    # It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
    # running httpd, as with most system services.
    #
    User daemon
    Group daemon

    </IfModule>
    </IfModule>

    # 'Main' server configuration
    #
    # The directives in this section set up the values used by the 'main'
    # server, which responds to any requests that aren't handled by a
    # <VirtualHost> definition.  These values also provide defaults for
    # any <VirtualHost> containers you may define later in the file.
    #
    # All of these directives may appear inside <VirtualHost> containers,
    # in which case these default settings will be overridden for the
    # virtual host being defined.
    #

    #
    # ServerAdmin: Your address, where problems with the server should be
    # e-mailed.  This address appears on some server-generated pages, such
    # as error documents.  e.g. admin@your-domain.com
    #
    ServerAdmin postmaster@localhost

    #
    # ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
    # This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
    # it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
    #
    # If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
    #
    ServerName localhost:80


    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"

    #
    #

    #
    <Directory />
        AllowOverride none
        Require all denied
    </Directory>


    # XAMPP: We disable operating system specific optimizations for a listening 
    # socket by the http protocol here. IE 64 bit make problems without this.  
    AcceptFilter http none



    #
    # This should be changed to whatever you set DocumentRoot to.
    #
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">


        # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
        # for more information.
        #
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI

        #

        # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
        #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
        #
        AllowOverride All

        #
        # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
        #
        Require all granted

    </Directory>

    #
    # DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
    # is requested.
    #
    <IfModule dir_module>
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.asp index.shtml index.html index.htm \
                       default.php default.pl default.cgi default.asp default.shtml default.html default.htm \
                       home.php home.pl home.cgi home.asp home.shtml home.html home.htm
    </IfModule>

    #
    # The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
    # viewed by Web clients. 
    #
    <Files ".ht*">
        Require all denied
    </Files>

    #
    # ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
    # If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
    # container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
    # logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
    # container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
    #
    ErrorLog "logs/error.log"

    #ScriptLog "logs/cgi.log"

    #
    # LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    #
    LogLevel warn

    <IfModule log_config_module>
        #
        # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
        # a CustomLog directive (see below).
        #
        LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
        LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

        <IfModule logio_module>
          # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
          LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
        </IfModule>

        #
        # The location and format of the access logfile (Common Logfile Format).
        # If you do not define any access logfiles within a <VirtualHost>
        # container, they will be logged here.  Contrariwise, if you *do*
        # define per-<VirtualHost> access logfiles, transactions will be
        # logged therein and *not* in this file.
        #
        #CustomLog "logs/access.log" common

        #
        # If you prefer a logfile with access, agent, and referer information
        # (Combined Logfile Format) you can use the following directive.
        #
        CustomLog "logs/access.log" combined
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule alias_module>
        #
        # Redirect: Allows you to tell clients about documents that used to 
        # exist in your server's namespace, but do not anymore. The client 
        # will make a new request for the document at its new location.
        # Example:
        # Redirect permanent /foo http://localhost/bar

        #
        # Alias: Maps web paths into filesystem paths and is used to
        # access content that does not live under the DocumentRoot.
        # Example:
        # Alias /webpath /full/filesystem/path
        #
        # If you include a trailing / on /webpath then the server will
        # require it to be present in the URL.  You will also likely
        # need to provide a <Directory> section to allow access to
        # the filesystem path.

        #
        # ScriptAlias: This controls which directories contain server scripts. 
        # ScriptAliases are essentially the same as Aliases, except that
        # documents in the target directory are treated as applications and
        # run by the server when requested rather than as documents sent to the
        # client.  The same rules about trailing "/" apply to ScriptAlias
        # directives as to Alias.
        #
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "C:/xampp/cgi-bin/"

    </IfModule>

    <IfModule cgid_module>
        #
        # ScriptSock: On threaded servers, designate the path to the UNIX
        # socket used to communicate with the CGI daemon of mod_cgid.
        #
        #Scriptsock "logs/cgi.sock"
    </IfModule>

    #
    # "C:/xampp/cgi-bin" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
    # CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
    #
    <Directory "C:/xampp/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>


    <IfModule mime_module>
        #
        # TypesConfig points to the file containing the list of mappings from
        # filename extension to MIME-type.
        #
        TypesConfig "conf/mime.types"

        #
        # AddType allows you to add to or override the MIME configuration
        # file specified in TypesConfig for specific file types.
        #
        #AddType application/x-gzip .tgz
        #
        # AddEncoding allows you to have certain browsers uncompress
        # information on the fly. Note: Not all browsers support this.
        #
        #AddEncoding x-compress .Z
        #AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz

        #
        # If the AddEncoding directives above are commented-out, then you
        # probably should define those extensions to indicate media types:
        #
        AddType application/x-compress .Z
        AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

        #
        # AddHandler allows you to map certain file extensions to "handlers":
        # actions unrelated to filetype. These can be either built into the server
        # or added with the Action directive (see below)
        #
        # To use CGI scripts outside of ScriptAliased directories:
        # (You will also need to add "ExecCGI" to the "Options" directive.)
        #
        AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .asp

        # For type maps (negotiated resources):
        #AddHandler type-map var

        #
        # Filters allow you to process content before it is sent to the client.
        #
        # To parse .shtml files for server-side includes (SSI):
        # (You will also need to add "Includes" to the "Options" directive.)
        #
        AddType text/html .shtml
        AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mime_magic_module>
        #
        # The mod_mime_magic module allows the server to use various hints from the
        # contents of the file itself to determine its type.  The MIMEMagicFile
        # directive tells the module where the hint definitions are located.
        #
        MIMEMagicFile "conf/magic"
    </IfModule>

    #

    # XAMPP specific settings
    Include "conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf"

    # Server-pool management (MPM specific)
    Include "conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf"

    # Multi-language error messages
    Include "conf/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf"

    # Fancy directory listings
    Include "conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf"

    # Language settings
    Include "conf/extra/httpd-languages.conf"

    # User home directories
    Include "conf/extra/httpd-userdir.conf"

    # Real-time info on requests and configuration
    Include "conf/extra/httpd-info.conf"

    # Virtual hosts
    Include "conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf"

    # Distributed authoring and versioning (WebDAV)
    # Attention! WEB_DAV is a security risk without a new userspecific configuration for a secure authentifcation 
    # Include "conf/extra/httpd-dav.conf"

    # Implements a proxy/gateway for Apache.
    Include "conf/extra/httpd-proxy.conf"

    # Various default settings
    Include "conf/extra/httpd-default.conf"

    # Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
    Include "conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf"
    #
    # Note: The following must must be present to support
    #       starting without SSL on platforms with no /dev/random equivalent
    #       but a statically compiled-in mod_ssl.
    #
    <IfModule ssl_module>
        SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
        SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
    </IfModule>

    # Configure mod_proxy_html to understand HTML4/XHTML1
    #<IfModule proxy_html_module>
    #Include etc/extra/proxy-html.conf
    #</IfModule>

    # AJP13 Proxy
    <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    <IfModule mod_proxy_ajp.c>
    Include "conf/extra/httpd-ajp.conf"
    </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    PHPIniDir "C:/PHP"
```

Comment: try looking at apaches error log. you may want to reconfigure apache's `LogLevel` to `debug`. Or, try starting apache.exe from the command line and hope it prints some error out.

Comment: What do your apache logs say?

Answer (score 3):

Do you have error log? Please post the relevent lines from there is you do. By default, Apache error log is under C:\xampp\apache\logs\error.log.

In addition, try to check which applications trying listening to port 80:

```
 Start -> Run -> cmd ->
 netstat -ano | findstr 80
```

You'll get the process ID's of the proccesses listening on port 80. Try to stop them. You can get the name of them by using the cmd, with the command:

```
 tasklist | findstr PROCCESS_ID
```

Known services that can interfere:

1. VMware (Stop the services starting with "VMWare" through services.msc)
2. Skype
3. (Anybody knows other ones?)

---

Another option: try to take the original, unchanged configurations file and revert your changes to see if Apache starts now.

Comment: No other services are using port 80, here's my error log from today
[Sat Jan 05 14:59:45.638800 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1452:tid 372] AH00430: Parent: Child process exited successfully.

Comment: xampp just freezes and suddenly no tresponding

Comment: Another option: try to take the original, unchanged configurations file and revert your changes to see if Apache starts now.

Comment: Can confirm that disabling the VMWare services fixed it for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

One more thing could help, as it did to me. If you have apache and mysql services checked in the control  panel, take them away, and do what is said in one of the answers with netstat -ano stuff. I had those problems too and thank God they disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

```
#Listen 0.0.0.0:80
#Listen [::]:80
Listen 80
```

change this to

```
#Listen 0.0.0.0:80
#Listen [::]:80
Listen localhost:80
```

Answer (score -1):

It's a lot of stuff but I think I identified one errors in `php.ini`

Here you close the tag `<Directory />` - remove the backslash

```
    <Directory />
        AllowOverride none
        Require all denied
    </Directory>
```